# How do I securely connect to my server on all ports/protocols?

Tags: networking, vpn

Some protocols (Samba) do not always encrypt data. Whenever my computer establishes a connection with my server on any port, I would like that connection to be encrypted and forwarded as a proxy… The server is to be tricked into thinking the connection is local.

VPN is not a solution since all connections, regardless of its destination, is forwarded to the server. I only want connections between my computer and the server to be encrypted.

Does such software exist?

Comment: Just use encrypted communications standards.  There is no universal solution.  A VPN works because the initial connection to the VPN server is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

> VPN is not a solution since all connections, regardless of its destination, is forwarded to the server.

**That is not true.** If you configure the VPN client to set the server as the default gateway, then everything will go through the server. If you don't – it won't. Regardless of the VPN protocol, it is perfectly possible to have a connection where only (for example) `10.0.0.0/8` is routed over the VPN connection.

Though, if you only have one server, most VPN protocols won't be very useful because of the *exact opposite* problem – communications with the VPN server obviously cannot go over the VPN.

**IPSec** in transport mode would work really well in this case; it is pretty much designed to secure all traffic directly between two hosts. For Linux, install either strongSwan or LibreSwan. For Windows, dig through the "Windows Firewall Advanced" console.

Comment: Well, that’s not exactly true. You *can* send traffic to the VPN server through the VPN connection—you just can’t use the IP address the VPN services is listening on. So the VPN subnet (if any) or other IP addresses of the server (if any) are reachable through VPN tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

Stunnel (https://www.stunnel.org) may be of use, but as grawity pointed out, a VPN is a solution as well.